# Duplicate series added Javafx

Tags: javafx

I try to build a simple JavaFX application using `LineChart`. I want to add save all the series that I added in the graph, click after click.

I saw other responses about this problem, but even if i cleaned all the Lists of my Service class, there are duplicated Series displayed.

Here is my code:

**Application**

```
public class App extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    BorderPane b = new BorderPane();
    MyService ser  =new MyService();
    LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    Button button = new Button("start");

    Button button1 = new Button("start2");
    button.setOnAction(((event)->{
        ser.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED, //
                new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

                    @Override
                    public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {

                        chart.getData().add(ser.getValue());

                    }
                });


        ser.restart();

    }));

    button1.setOnAction(((event) ->{
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Math.random(), Math.random()));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Math.random(), Math.random()));
        series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Math.random(), Math.random()));
        chart.getData().add(series);
    }));



    b.setBottom(button);
    b.setCenter(chart);
    b.setLeft(button1);

    Scene sc = new Scene(b);


    stage.setScene(sc);
    stage.show();

}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

**My service class**

```
public class MyService extends Service<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> {
    @Override
    protected Task<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>> createTask() {
        return new Task<XYChart.Series<Number, Number>>() {
            @Override
            protected XYChart.Series<Number, Number> call() throws Exception {
                XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();


                series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Math.random(), Math.random()));
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Math.random(), Math.random()));
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Math.random(), Math.random()));


                return series;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

[We can see duplicated series with the labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEBD0.png)

maybe I have to go through a temporary variable then add the series outside the handle.
In this case it is good except that I have a null value of seriesTotal..

```
public class App extends Application {

    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    private XYChart.Series<Number, Number> seriesTotal = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();

    private LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane b = new BorderPane();
        MyService ser = new MyService();

        // Job j = new Job();
        Button button = new Button("start");
        Button button1 = new Button("start2");

        List<Object> test = new ArrayList<>();

        button.setOnAction(((event) -> {
            test.clear();
            ser.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED, //
                    new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {


                            seriesTotal = ser.getValue();
                            //test.add(ser.getValue());
                            //chart.getData().add(ser.getValue());


                        }

                    });



            ser.restart();

            System.out.println(seriesTotal);
            chart.getData().add(seriesTotal);
            seriesTotal.getData().clear();
        }));



        button1.setOnAction(((event) -> {
            XYChart.Series<Number, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Math.random(), Math.random()));
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Math.random(), Math.random()));
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<Number, Number>(Math.random(), Math.random()));
            chart.getData().add(series1);
            // chart.getData().setAll(arg0);
        }));

        b.setBottom(button);
        b.setCenter(chart);
        b.setLeft(button1);

        Scene sc = new Scene(b);

        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
enter code here
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what you'd expect? `chart.getData()` returns a `List`. So if you `add()` to the list, you put more elements in it. Lists are allowed to contain duplicate elements, so you just end up with the same series in the data multiple times. If you want to clear the list, call `clear()` before you call `add()`, or just call the convenience method `setAll()`.

Comment: I added another button which the setOnAction is what I expected ("start2")

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a confusion in your code; in your `button` event handler, you're using `chart.getData()` to insert new points to the screen, which is not the same thing as `series.getData()` in your `MyService` class.

Just to be clear :

```
LineChart<Number, Number>
|
| chart.getData()
|
V
Series<Number, Number>
|
| series.getData()
|
V
Data<Number, Number>
```

When you press the button in your application, you're not adding a point to the current series, you're adding a new series containing only one point which has been generated by your service. It might explain the series duplication on your screen.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your answer, but the purpose of my graph is to add multiple line on the graph, so I think i have to add severals Series (which represent a line i think), and not to add Data<Number,Number> to only one Series.

Comment: I see that you've decided to add multiple `Data<Number, Number>` to your `Series`, modifying your service is a good option to do what you wanted

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the handle of the service is executed several times for a click, by putting a counter (or boolean) as an attribute and set it on 0 on the button handle, to stop repetitions there is no more duplication.

```
public class App extends Application {


    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    private int count = 0;
    private LineChart<Number, Number> chart = new LineChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane b = new BorderPane();
        MyService ser = new MyService();

        // Job j = new Job();
        Button button = new Button("start");


        button.setOnAction(((event) -> {
            count = 0;

            ser.addEventHandler(WorkerStateEvent.WORKER_STATE_SUCCEEDED, //
                    new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {

                        @Override
                        public void handle(WorkerStateEvent t) {


                            if(count==0) {
                                chart.getData().add(ser.getValue());
                                count++;
                            }





                        }

                    });



            ser.restart();





        }));





        b.setBottom(button);
        b.setCenter(chart);


        Scene sc = new Scene(b);

        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }



}
```